# What is the most efficient way - checking tag or GetComponent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am thinking about the best way of checking is GameObject is Enemy or not. I can use CompareTag method to check if it is "Enemy" or try to get component for example "EnemyController", but i am confused. 
Can you tell me what is the most efficient way of doing things like this in Unity?

Thanks for your responds.

Comment: If you need to do something with the script (deal damage), getComponent is going to be needed anyway. Otherwise use tags, tags are very fast. If it is a question of *which* component, I suggest using interfaces or superclasses, so you can skip the decision entirely.

Comment: I heard that using tags==strings are not really good idea, because of garbage. So if i want to for example check if clicked GO is Enemy or something else and do damage or other action should I rather try GetComponent(if null do something else) or rather check tag.

Comment: [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html). And in terms of garbage, all local variables contribute essentially zero garbage, strings or not.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find a good comparison about this;

https://snowhydra.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/unity-performance-testing-getcomponent-fields-tags/

As a result, using layers is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary that uses the Collider as the key and your script at the value. You need to manage it yourself when you and and remove items.

Comment: Do you think this solution will use a lot of memory, and create garbage?

Comment: It will use some memory but nothing significant, so far this is the most efficient way I’ve found for dealing with collisions and avoiding calling get components.

Comment: Dictionary is 1:1, I'm not sure that this is going to solve the Asker's question.